# Can't remove Half-root caused by KingoRoot

Tags: unrooting, supersu, kingo

I have a Huawei AT&T Fusion 3 (Y536A1) with Android 4.4.3 which I attempted to root with KingoRoot but it ended up giving me a half-root after testing it with the Freedom app.

I tried uninstalling it using the KingoRoot Superuser, but it just deletes the Superuser app and restarts but doesn't delete the root itself. I tried manually deleting the su files (with Root Explorer and ES File Explorer), but I don't have the right permissions to do so. I also tried using SuperSU but the binaries always failed to update and when I tried full unroot it still didn't unroot. I also tried to install KingRoot over KingoRoot but it said that it couldn't root (even though the device is compatible).

How do I remove this half root so I can fully root?

Comment: Use [SuperSUme](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=darkslide.com.supersumepro&hl=en) The Latest version supports New versions of kingroot. This app allows switching of Kingroot(so reinstall that) to SuperSU.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a PC, then you must download the Huawei PC Suite (HiSuite)from its website (Huawei) and do SW update of your smartphone by USB connection as many times. It will do the works according to the reviews I listened to.

Another method is to find the root files using ES File Explorer and you have to track those files by browsing to system files that are written on the Kingoroot website. The next step is to delete those files but be careful as this requires expertise.

This must work as I have checked.